# FreeBSD in USB Flash Drive

Tags: freebsd, usb, boot

I like to use live FreeBSD in my USB flash drive. How can i do it ?

Please give clear way to do it.

Comment: If I search for "FreeBSD on USB" I get thousands of howtos and tutorial. What is your exact question? What have you did to achive your goal already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/ and download and install their software. Start the application, choose FreeBSD 8 as distribution and your USB stick at the bottom of the dialog and hit ok.

Answer (score 5):

Nowadays you can just download the `memstick` image from FreeBSD, from the documentation on their download page:

> memstick This can be written to an USB memory stick (flash drive) and
>   used to do an install on machines capable of booting off USB drives.
>   It also supports booting into a "livefs" based rescue mode. The
>   documentation packages are provided but no other packages.
>
> As one example of how to use the memstick image, assuming the USB
>   drive appears as /dev/da0 on your machine something like this should
>   work:

```
# dd if=FreeBSD-8.2-RELEASE-amd64-memstick.img of=/dev/da0 bs=10240 conv=sync
```